# NSDateFormatter "Month" in 3 letters instead of full word

Tags: ios, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter, monthcalendar

```
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm"];        
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

If i choose `MM` i get the month in number: `09-05-2012 15:33`
If i choose `MMMM` i get the month in word: `09-May-2012 15:33`

What i wanted, was the month in 3 letters abbreviation.
Eg: `January` would be `Jan`

In this case May is correct because it only has 3 letters.

Comment: Use `MMM` for short month name

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have you tried: `[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm"];` and then `[formatter stringFromDate:someNSDate];`

Comment: M gives me number MMM gives me full word

Comment: Maybe you are right, i´m trying with May. Should use a different month, but i´m on the simulator...

Comment: Hahaha, "May" is the only non-conclusive month to test this on.

Comment: This post helped me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969183/nsdateformatter-fails-parsing-three-letter-abbreviation-of-german-month-march-ju

Answer (score 32):

IF you get the two things in the wrong order, you don't get the expected output.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

does NOT give the same results as:

```
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
```

(The second of these two snippets is now happily handing out Sep Oct etc in my app)

Comment: dateStyle and dateFormat are different things.
One overrides the other, `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle` uses the system wide format for short dates, while setting the `dateFormat` to `MMM` specifies that only the shot month value should be used.

Answer (score 9):

In **SWIFT**

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"

dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a stripped down solution that works with Swift 4 in producing a 3 letter month output:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss"
```

And to verify:

```
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())) // 20 Mar 2018, 23:41:40
```

As previously noted, `MMM` is the correct syntax for getting the desired month output.

Answer (score 3):

for swift 4 go with:

```
if let dateFormatter = DateFormatter(){
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    // eventually:
    //let locale = Locale(identifier: ...                       
    //dateFormatter!.locale = locale
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter!.dateFormat = "dd MMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss"
 } else..
        ..
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can set your dateStyle to medium (ie 'Jan', 'Feb' etc) like this:

```
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who do not get a full month strong with "MMM", you can get it with

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
```

Tested on Swift 4.2